# Resize window to fit its each new content in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, resize, window

I have a dialog window that its content is always changing. When the content grows up then the window also grows up. But, when the content became smaller it  shows in the most sized window again. I want to resize the window for each new content. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe, but it wasn't explained as mine. And the solution isn't there.

Comment: One answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760211/6165833

Comment: Also see this Qt Forum thread: [Resize top level window to fit contents](https://forum.qt.io/post/80850).