# Pyqt: Enforcing sizeHint() dimensions on two-widget app with layout manager

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qsizepolicy

I have two widgets residing one next to each other, `WidgetA` and `WidgetB`, on a `QDialog`, with a horizontal Layout Manager.
I am trying to enforce the following size/resize policies:
For **`WidgetA`**:

- Horizontally: Width should be 900 with the ability to shrink (up to 100), and to expand (to whatever).
- Vertically: Height should be 600 with the ability to expand (to whatever).

For **`WidgetB`**:

- Horizontally: Width should be Fixed to 600.
- Vertically: Height should be 600, with the ability to expand (to whatever) - same as `WidgetA`.

But no matter which size policy I choose for WidgetA, it still won't take up width of 900.
Here's a code sample:

```
class WidgetA(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WidgetA, self).__init__(parent)
        #self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)   --> WidgetA width still smaller than 900
        #self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Ignored, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)     --> WidgetA will be set to minimumSizeHint()
        #self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)       --> not good for me, since I want WidgetA to be able to shrink up to minimumSizeHint().width()
        #self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)     --> not good for me for the same reason - I want WidgetA to be able to shrink up to minimumSizeHint().width()

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return QSize(100, 600)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(900, 600) 


class WidgetB(QTextEdit):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(WidgetB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(600, 600)

class MainForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        label_a = QLabel('A')
        widget_a = WidgetA()
        label_a.setBuddy(widget_a)

        label_b = QLabel('B')
        widget_b = WidgetB()
        label_b.setBuddy(widget_b)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label_a)
        vbox.addWidget(widget_a)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

        hbox.addWidget(widget)

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(label_b)
        vbox.addWidget(widget_b)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(vbox)

        hbox.addWidget(widget)

        self.setLayout(hbox)



def run_app():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_app()
```

The closest I could get is when I set:

```
self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
```

On `WidgetA`.

[image]

It seems like `WidgetB` is taking a bite off of `WidgetA`'s 900 width (eliminating `WidgetB` does the trick), but I shouldn't be limited by the window's width.
What's preventing from the **window itself** (the `MainForm`) to automatically expand horizontally in order to account for both `WidgetA`'s 900 width and `WidgetB`'s fixed 600 width?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the article on [Layout Management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), the rules applied when adding widgets are as follows:

> 1. All the widgets will initially be allocated an amount of space in accordance with their QWidget::sizePolicy() and QWidget::sizeHint().
> 2. If any of the widgets have stretch factors set, with a value greater than zero, then they are allocated space in proportion to
>      their stretch factor (explained below).
> 3. If any of the widgets have stretch factors set to zero they will only get more space if no other widgets want the space. Of these,
>      space is allocated to widgets with an Expanding size policy first.
> 4. Any widgets that are allocated less space than their minimum size (or minimum size hint if no minimum size is specified) are allocated
>      this minimum size they require. (Widgets don't have to have a minimum
>      size or minimum size hint in which case the stretch factor is their
>      determining factor.)
> 5. Any widgets that are allocated more space than their maximum size are allocated the maximum size space they require. (Widgets do not
>      have to have a maximum size in which case the stretch factor is their
>      determining factor.)

So the most you can do is to define `sizeHint` and `minimumSizeHint`, set a stretch factor greater than all the others, and set a size-policy of `Expanding`. But even with all these things in place, it seems the layout manager is *still* not guaranteed to honour the size-hint when the minimum-size-hint is less.

The problem is that the definition of [`Expanding`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) is not *quite* strong enough:

> The sizeHint() is a sensible size, but the widget can be shrunk and
>   still be useful. The widget can make use of extra space, so it should
>   get as much space as possible (e.g. the horizontal direction of a
>   horizontal slider).

For whatever reason, the layout manager seems to prioritise shrinking over expanding if another widget has a stronger size-policy (e.g. `Fixed`). This looks like the wrong choice from the point of view of your example, but I suppose there may be other situations where it makes more sense. The behaviour seems to be exactly the same in both Qt4 and Qt5, so I don't know whether it should be considered a bug, or just a quirk of the implementation.

The simplest work-around I could come up with to fix your example is to enforce the size-hint of `widget_a` like this:

```
class MainForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        ...

        self.setLayout(hbox)

        widget_a.setMinimumSize(widget_a.sizeHint())
        self.adjustSize()
        widget_a.setMinimumSize(widget_a.minimumSizeHint())
```

(NB: only tested on Linux with the Openbox window manager).

PS: see also this quite similar SO question: [Resize window to fit content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16468235/984421).

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
I also sensed that the definition of `Expanding` is not strong enough.
I think the suggested workaround will do just fine.